# Appending a text file with a 2D array

Tags: java, append, multidimensional-array

I have a method to store the input of a 2D array in a `.txt` file. However, even with the true put on the end of `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("CBB.dat");`, something that usually allows for appending in past projects, the file still only receives one entry before writing over it with the next entry. How would this be fixed?

```
public void Save(String[][] EntryList)
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File("CBB.dat");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        if (EntryList[0][0] != null)
        {
            DataOutputStream outstream;
            outstream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
            for (int row = 0; row < EntryList.length; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < EntryList[row].length; col++)
                {
                    if (EntryList[row][col] != null) outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][col]);
                }

                outstream.close();
            }
        }
        else System.out.print("Something is wrong");
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) instead of a `String[][]` (or you could also use [variable arity parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)):

```
public static void save(CharSequence entryList)
    {
        BufferedReader read;
        BufferedWriter write;
        File file = new File("CBB.dat");
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String complete = "";
            String line = null;
            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null)
            {
                complete += line + "\n";
            }
            read.close();
            write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            write.append(complete);
            write.append(entryList);
            write.flush();
            write.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not too knowledgeable on `charsequences`. Can I assign multiple strings to one?

Comment: Yes. A [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) functions much like a `String`.